# Yii RBAC issue in putty

Tags: php, yii

In the slides im reading for creating user auth i have to install rbaccommand.php in the protect/commands/shell folder.

My Rbac is the one found here http://pastebin.com/uENRQ5Nz

i have this in my config/main.php

`'authManager'=>array(
'class' => 'CDbAuthManager',
'connectionID' => 'db', 
),`

and this is the line i put into the command line. `php yiic.php shell config/main.php` i'm supposed to type yes afterwards but it states rbac isn't found.

Am i missing a step?

Sam

Comment: Please paste the code here rather than your pastebin link, so your post will still be relevant if pastebin url is no longer available.

Comment: You are typing the command wrong. Use php yiic.php rbac. Also, change console.php with the db details.